# Time In Datatable MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

hello i want to display just the time in my datatable but it show [object object] here is the code

```
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dechargements/GetList",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id_Train" },
                    {
                        data: "date_dechargement",
                        type: "date",
                         render: function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data != null) {
                                var dtStart = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
                                return dtStart.toLocaleDateString();

                            } else {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        data: "debut_de_déchargement",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knbzd.png)

Comment: The code you shared is for `date_dechargement` which should work fine( it returns the date). share the relevant code which is printing the object now. What is inside the object ?

Comment: here is the code for for time [object] [object]   {
                            data: "debut_de_déchargement",
                             type: "time",
                 

                        },

Comment: data: "debut_de_déchargement",
                            type: "time",
                            render: function (value) {
                                if (value === null) return "";

                                var pattern = /Date([)]+)([^)]+)([)]+)/;
                                var results = pattern.exec(value);
                                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

                                return dt.getTime;
                            }

Comment: use  moment.js javascript libry to convert your default date into time.

Comment: i  downloaded the Moment.js library but I still have the same problem

Comment: pleas I do not always get to show the hour in my datatable

Comment: after data != null, type console.log(data)  and see what is inside data,could you please show what is inside that data on console ?